# Spring Batch EnableBatchProcessing JobParameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

All,

I have a configuration similar to the following.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyConfiguration {

  @Bean
  protected Job myJob() { return <the-job>; }

  @Bean
  protected JobParameters params() { return <parameters>; }

}
```

I had assumed that this would use the `JobParameters` bean which I specified, but it does not. How do I use both `@EnableBatchProcessing` and `JobParameters`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@EnableBatchProcessing provides you with some useful beans like the *JobLauncher* ([further info](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/EnableBatchProcessing.html)). To inject your specified job parameters, pass them to the method actually launching your job.

```
@Autowired
JobLauncher jobLauncher;

public void startExecution() {
    jobLauncher.run(job, jobParemeters);
}
```

If I understand correctly, you know how to access your jobParameters in your step configuration like this

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public SomeProcessor processor(@Value("#{jobParameters['someParameter']}") String param) {
    ...
}
```

@EnableBatchProcessing will run available jobs on startup by default. Setting

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

in your *application.properties* will disable this feature.

Comment: So I'm able to get the `JobLauncher`, but it doesn't quite work. Previously, I didn't have any method which launched the job. It just kind of does it on its own.

After I run the job, the `@EnableBatchProcessing` tries to run the job again, this time without the parameters.

Comment: You can disable auto launching of Jobs by setting _spring.batch.job.enabled=false_ in your application.properties file.